# ksoap2 - Android app calling webservice to update remote database - runs but does not record

Tags: android, web-services, soap

***Objective:*** The app calls a webservice sending 5 parameters that identify the selection criteria to exchange status in remote database table. The webservice response is the literal OK, that is, normal execution.

***Problem:*** Webservice usually runs without errors (no exceptions), but to check the remote database no update has been recorded. It is as if the Webservice run unrealized commit. No error is shown during the application debug. It all makes me believe that the error is in my app because when running the same webservice by SoapUI 5.0.0 software the database is updated correctly. I do not have advanced knowledge to solve this problem. I thank you for your help!
Any tips on how to debug this problem is welcome.

***Possible cause:*** Apparently the parameters are being passed properly (see below the xml's request that was compared to the xml sent by SoapUI that works perfectly). Is there any way to know how the xml request came in webservice? How to debug it?

Thanks to the tutorial:http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-webservice-example/

Example SOAP 1.1 webservice (extracted definition of the WSDL)

```html
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.
POST /wsv_teste/wsv.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.154.1.15
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/set_Bloqueia"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <set_Bloqueia xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Num>int</Num>
      <DataAtual>string</DataAtual>
      <Rua>string</Rua>
      <Atividade>string</Atividade>
      <ARB>string</ARB>
    </set_Bloqueia>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <set_BloqueiaResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

***Debug app, step 1 - HttpTransportSE.request***

```html
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <set_Bloqueia xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Num>99</Num>
      <DataAtual>24-AUG-2011</DataAtual>
      <Rua>USJ-111</Rua>
      <Atividade>LU</Atividade>
      <ARB>LIN_PROP</ARB>
    </set_Bloqueia>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

***Debug app, step 2 - HttpTransportSE.response***

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <set_BloqueiaResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <set_BloqueiaResult>OK</set_BloqueiaResult>
    </set_BloqueiaResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

***SoapUI test - in which the WS works perfectly (request)***

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:set_Bloqueia>
         <tem:Num>99</tem:Num>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:DataAtual>24-AUG-2011</tem:DataAtual>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Rua>USJ-111</tem:Rua>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Atividade>LU</tem:Atividade>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:ARB>LIN_PROP</tem:ARB>
      </tem:set_Bloqueia>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

***SoapUI test - in which the WS works perfectly (response)***

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <set_BloqueiaResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <set_BloqueiaResult>OK</set_BloqueiaResult>
      </set_BloqueiaResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

***Application source code (only the essential)***

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.opcoes_baixar);

    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
    task.execute();


private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            testeBloqRua();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            tv.setText(resultado);
            formandoLayouts();//        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            tv.setText("**Carregando...");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }
    }

public void testeBloqRua() {

    String HOST = "http://10.154.1.15";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://10.154.1.15/wsv_teste/";
    String URL = "http://10.154.1.15/wsv_teste/wsv.asmx";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/set_Bloqueia";
    String METHOD_NAME = "set_Bloqueia";
    String resultWS = null;
    SoapObject requestBloquear = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", METHOD_NAME);
    //Campos necessarios para bloquear
    PropertyInfo bloquearNumPI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo bloquearDataAtualPI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo bloquearRuaPI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo bloquearAtividadePI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo bloquearArbPI = new PropertyInfo();
    //Num
    bloquearNumPI.setType(Integer.class);
    bloquearNumPI.setName("Num");
    bloquearNumPI.setValue(99);
            requestBloquear.addProperty(bloquearNumPI);
    //DataAtual
    bloquearDataAtualPI.setType(String.class);
    bloquearDataAtualPI.setName("DataAtual");
    bloquearDataAtualPI.setValue("24-AUG-2011");
    requestBloquear.addProperty(bloquearDataAtualPI);
    //Rua
    bloquearRuaPI.setType(String.class);
    bloquearRuaPI.setName("Rua");
    bloquearRuaPI.setValue("USJ-111");
    requestBloquear.addProperty(bloquearRuaPI);
    //Atividade
    bloquearAtividadePI.setType(String.class);
    bloquearAtividadePI.setName("Atividade");
    bloquearAtividadePI.setValue("LU");
    requestBloquear.addProperty(bloquearAtividadePI);
    //Arb
    bloquearArbPI.setType(String.class);
    bloquearArbPI.setName("ARB");
    bloquearArbPI.setValue("LIN_PROP");
    requestBloquear.addProperty(bloquearArbPI);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopeBloquear = new   SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   // 
    envelopeBloquear.dotNet=true;
    envelopeBloquear.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelopeBloquear.implicitTypes=true;
    envelopeBloquear.setOutputSoapObject(requestBloquear);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpBloquear = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try

    {
        androidHttpBloquear.debug = true;
        androidHttpBloquear.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelopeBloquear);
        SoapObject responseBloquear = (SoapObject) envelopeBloquear.bodyIn;

        resultWS = androidHttpBloquear.responseDump;

        Log.i("t", "doInBackground");
    }

    catch(Exception e )    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to put on hold as 'simple typographical error'.

Answer (score 0):

Your web services' variables should be like that

```
String HOST = "http://10.154.1.15";
String NAMESPACE = "http://10.154.1.15/wsv_teste/";
String URL = "http://10.154.1.15/wsv_teste/wsv.asmx";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.154.1.15/wsv_teste/";
String METHOD_NAME = "set_Bloqueia";
```

And replace this

```
SoapObject requestBloquear = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", METHOD_NAME);
```

with

```
SoapObject requestBloquear = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I finally found the problem. The error is one of the soap-request xml elements. The "ABR" is wrong. The correct name is "ARB". There was a reversal in the characters. I lost at least two days to find it. I apologize for this naive error.